# Design an algorithm to calculate stock prices on a given day

Tags: graphs, python

Given a list of lists containing tuples in sorted(by day) order find and print the total number of stock units owned for every day that occurs at least once.

```
#first  number in each tuple represents a day, second number represents how many units of that stock is owned.
#if a day is missing, you can assume the stock value didn't change from the previous entry.
#example number of msft stocks owned on day 1 is 300 and there is no input for day 2, so day 2 is 300
#notice that the stock number can decrease, google went down from its last reported day (2) to (5) by 300 units

#print the total number of stocks owned on every day that occurs in the stock_input

#expected values for the example input:
1 - 400
2 - 1000
3 - 1400
5 - 1100

stock_input = []

msft = [(1,300),(3,500)]
amzn = [(1,100),(2,300),(3,500)]
goog = [(2,400),(5,100)]

stock_input.append(msft)
stock_input.append(amzn)
stock_input.append(goog)
```

I'm not sure how exactly to attack this problem. I think it would involve some sort of flood fill type algorithm, but the gap in dates makes it a bit harder than a standard DFS because you have to know which day to search for.

Answer (score -1):

```
def calculateTotalStocks(stock_data):
    min_day = float("inf")  # minimum day in all stocks
    max_day = float("-inf") # maximum day in all stocks
    for i in stock_data:    # loop through all stocks
        for j in i:       # loop through all days in a stock
            min_day = min(min_day, j[0])    # find minimum day
            max_day = max(max_day, j[0])    # find maximum day
    stock_dict = dict().fromkeys(range(min_day, max_day+1), 0)  # create a dictionary with all days as keys and 0 as values
    for stock in stock_data:                                 # loop through all stocks
        counts = dict().fromkeys(range(stock[0][0], max_day+1), 0)  # create a dictionary with starting day as in stock and max day as ending day
        for idx, count in stock:                             # loop through all days in a stock
            counts[idx] = count                             # add count to dictionary
        prev = stock[0][0]                                 # set previous day to starting day of stock
        for key in range(stock[0][0]+1, max_day+1):       # loop through all days in dictionary after starting day
            if counts[key] == 0:                    # if count is 0
                counts[key] = counts[prev]       # set count to previous count
                prev = key                     # set previous day to current day
            else:                             # if count is not 0
                prev = key                   # set previous day to current day
        for key in counts:               # loop through all days in dictionary
            stock_dict[key] += counts[key]  # add count to total count
    return stock_dict           # return dictionary

def main(): # main function
    stock_input = []    # create empty list

    msft = [(1,300),(3,500)]    # create list for Microsoft
    amzn = [(1,100),(2,300),(3,500)]    # create list for Amazon
    goog = [(2,400),(5,100)]    # create list for Google

    stock_input.append(msft)    # add Microsoft to list
    stock_input.append(amzn)    # add Amazon to list
    stock_input.append(goog)    # add Google to list
    
    ans = calculateTotalStocks(stock_input)   # calculate total stocks
    for k, val in ans.items():              # loop through all days in dictionary
        print(f"{k} - {val}")            # print day and count

# Entry point of program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  # call main function
```

Comment: We're not a coding site, and we're not looking for answers that consist solely of code.  Instead, we'd prefer answers that contain ideas, explanation, concise pseudocode, etc.

Comment: sorry I answered my own question so I thought a full solution would be acceptable.